# Answering a question when I feel like there are better answers

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes, I approach a problem and I find myself pit up against an answer I deem as very good.  I upvote it, and then I get a feeling of 'incompleteness'.  I want to post an answer of my own, but by the time I am done typing up my answer, I feel the other answer is much better than my own in the first place.

I don't want to point out any specific posts, but I've found myself in this situation every so often.

Is it recommended that I post the answer anyways (where my answer is unique and correct) or make a few comments on anything that catches my attention and leave my answer in my mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard to answer this in abstract as it will depend on the type of post, and while you tried to describe it, it is hard to know what you mean precisely.

Just post such answers a few times and pay attention how they are received. 
Over time you will get a feel if the reception of such answers is positive, negative or neutral.

Generally, it is better to write a post rather than to "make a few comments."

Comment: I've found that doing both in some mixed way has worked for me well recently.

Comment: Glad to hear thinks worked out for you.